# SonarQube Java issues

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1, sonarqube-web

I am trying to retreive SonarQube results using Java API's.
While I am able to successfully retreive some results, I am facing few challenges as well.
I have following 2 problems

**Problem 1 :** 
My code is as follows

```
IssueQuery issueQuery = IssueQuery.create();
issueQuery.severities("MAJOR", "MINOR");
IssueClient issueClient = sonarClient.issueClient();
Issues issues = issueClient.find(issueQuery);
List<Issue> issueList = issues.list();
```

issues.list() in above code always gives 100 results only. Don't know how to configure this parameter to fetch all results. Can you please let me know how to retrive all issues?

**Problem 2** : While above code returns results for all projects.
Is there any way I can retrive issues for single project?
I tried the following code but it does not seem to be working.

```
IssueQuery issueQuery = IssueQuery.create();
issueQuery.issues(projKey1, projKey2);
IssueClient issueClient = sonarClient.issueClient();
Issues issues = issueClient.find(issueQuery);
List<Issue> issueList = issues.list();
System.out.println("No of issues = "+issueList.size());
```

issueList.size() is returning value 0
Can you please tell me how can I acheive this?

I searched a lot on internet but could not find any help?
Could you please help me n this regard?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: For problem 1: Obviously, there is some sort of page mechanism within IssueQuery. See Javadoc: http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/4.5.2/apidocs/org/sonar/wsclient/issue/IssueQuery.html    Without having tried, perhaps try `issueQuery.severities(...).pageSize(10000)`.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem 1**
Results are paginated. See `Issues#paging()` for the information about total number of results and `IssueQuery#pageIndex(int)` for requesting other pages.

**Problem 2**
The method `IssueQuery#componentRoots(String... projectKeys)` allows to filter on projects.

Comment: Hey Simon, thanks a lot for your response.
On issueQuery object I am not able to get componentRoots() method.
I am using sonar-ws-client.jar.
But I could get issueQuery.components() method instead.
So I tried with that but it is not working.
Following is my code

IssueQuery issueQuery = IssueQuery.create();

issueQuery = issueQuery.components(projKey1, projKey2);

IssueClient issueClient = sonarClient.issueClient();

Issues issues = issueClient.find(issueQuery);

List<Issue> issueList = issues.list();

System.out.println("No of issues = "+issueList.size());

Comment: which version of library ?

Comment: I am using sonar-ws-client-5.1.jar

Comment: Hey Simon, do you think I am missing something here?

Comment: You should check what are the results of web service `api/issues/search?componentKeys=projKey1`. See documentation at /api_documentation#api/issues.

Comment: Hey Simon, thank you again for your help.
If I use api/issues/search?componentKeys=projKey1. then I am getting result. But somehow through code it does not seem to be working. Could you please post sample code here in accordance with my library version?

Comment: Hi Simpon, I used library sonar-ws-client-5.0 and guess what I could make it work using the method named componentRoots(). Sadly this method is not there in v5.1
I just wondered why this method is removed in v5.1. Is there any other method that I need to use in v5.1?

Comment: ws-client is a simple layer to call api/issues/search web service, so I suggest that you have a look at the source code of v5.1. It maps exactly the parameters that you tested: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/5.1/server/sonar-ws-client/src/main/java/org/sonar/wsclient/issue/IssueQuery.java

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. But sadly there is no API named componentRoots() in version 5.1. You can verify it here
https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarqube/blob/5.1/server/sonar-ws-client/src/main/java/org/sonar/wsclient/issue/IssueQuery.java
Could you please let me know alternate API in version 5.1?